# Emacs showing grey background where there are no characters

Tags: emacs, gtk

Since a couple of days, my Emacs is showing a light grey background on
the parts of the window that are not covered by characters ([see
screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5toIW.jpg)).  Text appears normally black
on white (as per properties of the default face), but where there is
no text the color is light grey.

How can I restore the normal white background for the whole Emacs window?
(I suspect the problem is related to Emacs picking up some setting from
the GTK theme.)

Comment: It looks like a couple of things are going on -- maybe a hl-line (e.g., `highlight`) happening, and maybe a text setting with a specific background which is trumping your default background.  Are you using hl-line-mode (e.g., `highlight` face with a specifically defined background instead of `nil`)?  The commented out area is probably a third setting happening -- e.g., `font-lock-string-face`.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks! Yes, it's all correct (I have global hl mode, the grey backround in the first few lines is a custom font lock setting for comments), but that's not where the problem lies -- the issue is that the rest of the screen should be white like the text background  of the LISP form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem lies in the GTK-3.0 *Ambiance* theme.  I had
copied the theme in my `.config` directory (in addition to having it
in `/usr/share/themes`, following the suggestions in [this blog
post](http://babilonline.blogspot.ch/2012/01/gtk-theme-is-not-being-followed-by-all.html)).

File `gtk.css` starts with the line:

```
@define-color bg_color #f2f1f0;
```

and `#f2f1f0` is exactly the shade of grey that formed the Emacs
background.

Once I removed those files from `.config/gtk-3.0`, Emacs'
background turned back to white.

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is expected behavior (i.e., `.config` taking precedence over Emacs settings), or it is a bug in Emacs 24.

Comment: It is usually whatever loads later in time that controls -- e.g., you can have a setting high up in the configuration file that says the sky is blue and then lower down in the config file have the sky is red and the end result will be a red sky.  The same concept applies to files that are loaded subsequently to other files.  To help control this, there are three hooks -- before-init-hook, after-init-hook, and emacs-startup-hook -- and then mode-specific hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `@define-color bg_color ...` (or `theme_bg_color`) changes all your windows' backgrounds. If you instead put this in your Gtk3 gtk.css file, it will affect only emacs (version 24 at least):

```
EmacsFixed {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

.. replacing `#ffffff` with the background you want.

*Gtk3 loads `gtk.css` files from a number of places and merges their declarations together - I created a new one in `~/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` and that worked for me. If you have an existing one somewhere else - use that.*

Comment: To find out the name `EmacsFixed`, I run emacs like this: `GTK_DEBUG=size-request emacs` which prints a lot, but the information luckily was present in there.